# BeautifulSoup Parsed document different than original html page's code

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, spotify

I am using BeautifulSoup4 to do some scraping from Spotify Charts.

I have the code up and running fro some weeks. But suddenly today it started to fail. It started to give NaN values for all entries...

I believe the problem is in the  html parsed page. The resulting html code is different than the original webpage html.

I have tried with 'html.parses','lxml' and 'html5lib'. I also updated BeautifulSoup and all the parser's packages. But nothing

What could be the problem?
I have no idea what could be the root of the problem.Yesterday my Windows 10 was updated, could it be related?

Here is the part of the code that matters:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

u = 'https://spotifycharts.com/regional/us/daily/2021-04-18'

x = requests.get(u)  
a = bs(x.content,'html.parser')
tracks = a.find_all('td',class_='chart-table-position')
```

tracks is always none, because it does not exist in 'a'. But it should...because it exists in the webpage html and it existed some days ago...

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the user-agent in the headers solved this on my end. Give that a try:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests


u = 'https://spotifycharts.com/regional/us/daily/2021-04-18'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.190 Safari/537.36'}
x = requests.get(u, headers=headers)  
a = bs(x.content,'html.parser')
tracks = a.find_all('td',class_='chart-table-position')
```

**Output:**

```
print(len(tracks))
200
```

Comment: It did solve the problem. Thank you very much! Although I am curious of the 'why' of this solution

Comment: without it, it makes you look like a robot. If you print out what the response without the header it shows it's throwing you a CAPTCHA. So by putting your user-agent header in there it, it makes it look like a regular old browser accessing it.

Comment: Interesting...did not know that. Thank you very much for the help and explanation!